# Xamarin: Can I use maps without using Google Maps API?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to know if I can use Maps in Xamarin without using Google Maps API? Is it possible to have a Map without Google?

Comment: TL;DR; Yes... Pick a Map provider and implemented it ;-) Xamarin.Forms.Maps only uses Google Maps on Android, but you can always use the open source of Xamarin.Forms.Maps to code your own Map Provider to the existing interfaces if desired. Otherwise you can write your own API on top of whatever Map provider you choice...